# Java Regex to tokenize string

Tags: java, regex

This is my source string

```
substrb ( userenv ( 'CLIENT_INFO' ) , 1 , 1 ) , '' , null , substrb ( 'some_text'  , 1 , 10 )
```

I want to tokenize it in the following form

```
[1] : substrb ( userenv ( 'CLIENT_INFO' ) , 1 , 1 )
[2] : ''
[3] : null
[4] : substrb ( 'some_text'  , 1 , 10 )
```

Any Idea how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise writing a parser for this. All you need to do is count the number of currently open brackets and cut the string if there is a comma and the counter is at 0.

Something along the line of this:

```
int openBrackets = 0;
ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length; ++i) {
   char cc = inputString.charAt(i);
   if (cc == '(') openBrackets++;
   else if (cc == ')') openBrackets--;
   else if ((cc == ',') && (openBrackets == 0)) {
      tokens.add(tmp.toString());
      tmp.delete(0, tmp.length());
   }
   else tmp.append(cc);
}
if (tmp.length() > 0) tokens.add(tmp.toString());
```